# Deploying PhantomJS 2.5 beta on Heroku. How can I see what's failing?

Tags: heroku, phantomjs

I'm trying to make a custom buildpack to deploy PhantomJS 2.5 beta version on Heroku. [This is my buildpack](https://github.com/RamiroPinol/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs-2.5-beta) based on [Stomita's Phantomjs Buildpack](https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs) which runs version 2.1.1 and works fine.

This is what I get in the building process:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> PhantomJS app detected
remote: -----> Fetching PhantomJS 2.5.0-beta binaries at https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.5.0-beta-linux-ubuntu-trusty-x86_64.tar.gz
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile PhantomJS app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to rp-phantom.
remote:
```

As you can see, not much information. The binary is downloaded fine, I checked that omitting the -s flag in the curl command, but can't figure out what's failing.

This is my compile file:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

BUILD_DIR=$1
CACHE_DIR=$2

# config
VERSION="2.5.0-beta"

# Buildpack URL
ARCHIVE_NAME=phantomjs-${VERSION}-linux-ubuntu-trusty-x86_64
FILE_NAME=${ARCHIVE_NAME}.tar.gz
BUILDPACK_PHANTOMJS_PACKAGE=https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/${FILE_NAME}

mkdir -p $CACHE_DIR
if ! [ -e $CACHE_DIR/$FILE_NAME ]; then
  echo "-----> Fetching PhantomJS ${VERSION} binaries at ${BUILDPACK_PHANTOMJS_PACKAGE}"
  curl  $BUILDPACK_PHANTOMJS_PACKAGE -L -s -O $CACHE_DIR/$FILE_NAME
fi

echo "-----> Extracting PhantomJS ${VERSION} binaries to ${BUILD_DIR}/vendor/phantomjs"
mkdir -p $CACHE_DIR/$ARCHIVE_NAME
mkdir -p $BUILD_DIR/vendor
tar -xvf $CACHE_DIR/$FILE_NAME -C $CACHE_DIR
mv $CACHE_DIR/$ARCHIVE_NAME $BUILD_DIR/vendor/phantomjs

echo "-----> exporting PATH and LIBRARY_PATH"
PROFILE_PATH="$BUILD_DIR/.profile.d/phantomjs.sh"
mkdir -p $(dirname $PROFILE_PATH)
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/vendor/phantomjs/bin"' >> $PROFILE_PATH
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:vendor/phantomjs/lib"' >> $PROFILE_PATH
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get 2.5.0 beta working on Heroku. Here is my answer from my own [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42878323/how-to-use-phantomjs-2-5-0-beta-on-heroku):

---

Ultimately, I was able to figure it out! There are a few things that you have to do...

1. **Dependencies:** You have to use the [Heroku Apt buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt) to install the missing dependencies. First, you need to add the buildpack to your app:

   `heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt`

   Next, you'll create a file in your project root called `Aptfile`. Here's where we add the missing dependencies for PhantomJS 2.5.0 Beta. 2.5.0 introduces `webp` support, so we need that. `libhyphen0` is required as well, though I'm not sure how it us used. Finally, we use `gcc-5` and the latest `libstdc++6`. Contents should look like this:

```sh
webp
libhyphen0
https://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/gcc-5_5.4.1-8ubuntu1_amd64.deb
https://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_amd64.deb
```

2. **PhantomJS:** Next we grab the latest version of PhantomJS. I've created a [fork](https://github.com/lookitsatravis/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs.git) of the most [popular](https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs) PhantomJS buildpack and updated it for use with 2.5.0 beta. 2.5.0 beta has builds for `trusty` as well as `xenial`, so the build pack will detect the Heroku stack and use the appropriate one (though the cedar-16 stack is still in beta at the time of this post). So, add it to your app:

   `heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/lookitsatravis/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs.git`
3. **Deploy:** All that's left is deployment! Commit the `Aptfile` to your repo, make sure the build packs are setup, and then push to Heroku.

Took a bit of trial and error, but ultimately I was able to get it up and running. Hope this helps others until the final candidate is released.