# How to use PhantomJS 2.5.0 Beta on Heroku

Tags: ubuntu, heroku, phantomjs

Version 2.5.0 beta of PhantomJS is [available for use](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/phantomjs/AefOuwkgBh0/BsUiXD21DgAJ), but unlike stable versions, there are some dependencies for linux installations. I'm having trouble getting a working version on Heroku. I couldn't find a guide or any real answers in the Google group or elsewhere. How can I go about getting the installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, I was able to figure it out! There are a few things that you have to do...

#### TL;DR:

1. `heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt`
2. `heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/lookitsatravis/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs.git`
3. `cat > Aptfile << EOL
   webp
   libhyphen0
   https://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/gcc-5_5.4.1-8ubuntu1_amd64.deb
   https://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_amd64.deb
   EOL`
4. Commit `Aptfile`, push to Heroku app.

---

#### More info

1. **Dependencies:** You have to use the [Heroku Apt buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt) to install the missing dependencies. First, you need to add the buildpack to your app:

   `heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt`

   Next, you'll create a file in your project root called `Aptfile`. Here's where we add the missing dependencies for PhantomJS 2.5.0 Beta. 2.5.0 introduces `webp` support, so we need that. `libhyphen0` is required as well, though I'm not sure how it us used. Finally, we use `gcc-5` and the latest `libstdc++6`. Contents should look like this:

```sh
webp
libhyphen0
https://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/gcc-5_5.4.1-8ubuntu1_amd64.deb
https://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_amd64.deb
```

2. **PhantomJS:** Next we grab the latest version of PhantomJS. I've created a [fork](https://github.com/lookitsatravis/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs.git) of the most [popular](https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs) PhantomJS buildpack and updated it for use with 2.5.0 beta. 2.5.0 beta has builds for `trusty` as well as `xenial`, so the build pack will detect the Heroku stack and use the appropriate one (though the cedar-16 stack is still in beta at the time of this post). So, add it to your app:

   `heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/lookitsatravis/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs.git`
3. **Deploy:** All that's left is deployment! Commit the `Aptfile` to your repo, make sure the build packs are setup, and then push to Heroku.

Took a bit of trial and error, but ultimately I was able to get it up and running. Hope this helps others until the final candidate is released.

Comment: could you place make your procedure clearer? thank you

Comment: @Cody I added a TL;DR which will hopefully help. Sorry it wasn't clear enough initially!

Comment: Moved this comment from answer to here as you suggested. Thank you. I will try and figure it out. There is this click to deploy thing people do. Have you thought about doing that on your website? To help people deploy PJs on heroku.